# Multiple order quanity x price and show decimal two places

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I get the javascript and php to display two decimal places after calculation.  Right now it works fine but no decimal places, just whole numbers

php******************

```
      <td> width="3"><input type="text"  name="order_quan" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Price" /></td>
     <td><font color="yellow"><span class=Price></span></td>
```

Java Script****************

```
   <script>
   $('input[name=order_quan], input[name=Price]').keyup(function() {
     var divParent = $(this).closest('div');
   var order_quan = $('input[name=order_quan]', divParent).val()-0;
   var Price = $('input[name=Price]', divParent).val()-0;
    if (order_quan >= 0 && Price >= 0)
    $('span.Price', divParent).text(order_quan*Price);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .toFixed(2);

```
(order_quan * Price).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basics

```
String((order_quan*Price * 100)>>0).replace(/(\d{2}$)/,'.$1');
//shift it 2 decimal places left, floor it, and add '.' before the last two digits
```

Comment: Or use toFixed, like Karolis said, :$